# DHCP issues with two wireless APs and two different SSIDs on the same network

Tags: networking, dhcp, wifi-configuration, pfsense, dhcp-server

I have a small home network with a pfSense router running DHCP and DNS, as well as other services. This is directly connected to the internet via a modem, and then the other side connects to a switch.

I’ve been wanting to replace my aging WiFi access points and so I purchased a netgear orbi system and placed it in AP mode. I left my existing APs up so I could transition a few IoT devices. When I first connected, things seemed to work fine, but as the day went on I noticed some strange behavior.

If a device, say an iPhone, Windows laptop, or Mac laptop, was connected to my old SSID and then I chose to connect to the new SSID, that device would fail to obtain an IP address. Interestingly, if I connected back to the old SSID, it would get an IP immediately. If I turned WiFi off and then on again a few times, the device eventually gets an IP on the new SSID, but then fails to get an IP on the old one. Again, unless I turn WiFi off and on several times.

To level set, I rebooted all devices on the network. This did not fix anything. In the DHCP logs, the sequence looks something like this:

When I choose to switch SSIDs, the device sometimes issues a DHCPRELEASE.

I then see the device and my router go back and forth like this:

```
Device: DHCPDISCOVER
Router: DHCPOFFER
Device: DHCPDISCOVER
Router: DHCPOFFER
```

... This repeats a few times until finally

```
Router: DHCPOFFER
Device: DHCPREQUEST
Device: DHCPACK
```

Sometimes the router also shows a message in its log about reusing the lease.

When I run only a single AP, it works fine.

Is there something in the DHCP spec that prevents this from working? Or can I potentially change a setting that will remedy this? I used to used a Windows DCHP server on a VM, and I’m considering going back to that, but not if this is expected behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see this on the device side, or on the router side? Often this means the offer doesn't actually reach the device for some reason.

Comment: The issue was observed on the device. The router logs were posted as additional info. I wonder if it could be that the switch’s address table was still holding on to the old port assignment? I installed a new switch to support the NBASE-T ability of the orbi and the problem resolved itself